# Transferring Domain to Route53 - Email Access

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-route53

I am helping out a friends business who have had a falling out with their web developer, and I want to transfer their domain to Route53.

I have the domain password so I am going to shift everything across to Amazon.

However the email accounts "info@domain.com" and "admin@domain.com" were set up by the other developer, who have unfortunately cut all communication between my friend and them.

My question is what will happen to those email addresses after I transfer the domain, I presume they will shut down? Is there anyway to determine where an email account is hosted and thus determine it's MX records for Route53?

If they lose the account is it possible to register new emails with the same address after the transfer?

Comment: `dig MX domain.com`

Comment: Try `dig -t MX domainname.tld` (a Unix command) or [https://mxtoolbox.com/](https://mxtoolbox.com/).  Once you have control of DNS you can move email wherever you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

If you control the DNS servers, you can switch the MX record to a new host, which will give you complete control of your email.

You can do this in Amazon with Workmail, or set up something like gmail.

Any new emails will come into the new server.  You will not have access to any of the old emails however.

Comment: chris has provided the correct answer. I would like to add, if you own the domain, I would contact support for the current email provider. Normally they will give you back control for all email accounts. Usually they will ask you to add a TXT record to the domain so that they can verify who controls it. This happens a lot so it is not hard to correct. Be prepared to pay any outstanding balances first.